# Parametrizing Multiple Joins In EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to make a join in Entity Framework generic so that I can pass the entities and the join conditions. It should be able to make as many joins as needed. For example here I have two joins,

```
var result = (from outer in dbSet
              join inner1 in context.entity on outer.x1 equals inner1.id
              join inner2 in context.entity on outer.x2 equals inner2.id
              select new
              {
                  id = outer.id,
                  inner1,
                  inner2
              }
              )
             .ToList()
```

`context.entity` will be the same so I do not need it parametrized. I tried creating a utility method with signature `GetItemsWithTranslations<T>(DbSet<T> dbSet, List<Expression<Func<T, string>>> dbSetSelectors) where T:class` and tried using fluent syntax for multiple joins but since after each join, the next join requires the combined output signature of the previous one, I was not able to make it work.

Comment: EF doesn't need joins in the first place. It generates the joins itself based on the entity relations configured in the DbSet. Use proper relations and navigation properties in the context and all you'd need to load the entities would be eg `ctx.Employes.ToList()`

Comment: There are cases where it is not possible to use navigation properties such as when a relation in database points to a non-unique column.

Comment: And those cases are so rare that it's unclear why you would want some generic way to generate join queries.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It might not be as rare as you think actually, at least in the database I am currently working with.